# How would I test a function with an internal promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, jestjs

I am currently trying to write integration test to make sure that some specific client cases which have caused issues are not broken with further changes to a script. I am not sure how to properly format the test so that it runs and waits for the function to finish before returning:

1. Your test suite must contain at least one test.
2. The system calls the appropriate functions when mocked.

   ```
   // app.ts
   function doThing() {
       const data = window.data;
       if (!isEmpty(data)) {
           firstAsync(value1 => {
               return secondAsync(value1);
           }).then(value2 => {
               someCall();
           }).catch(error => {
               log(error);
           });
       } else {
           someOtherCall();
       }
   }

   // app.test.ts
   someCall = jest.fn();
   someOtherCall = jest.fn();

   describe('test', () => {
       it('should work', () => {
           window.data = { value: 'something' };
           doThing();

           expect(someCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
           expect(someOtherCall).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
   });
   ```

TL:DR - How would I write a test to cover a function that has a promise inside of it, but isn't a promise itself?

Comment: You really can't without modification.  The function itself does not return a result so there's no results to test.

Comment: Where did `someCall` and `someOtherCall` functions come from?